# Load Record by ID for View CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have what is probably a very basic question.  I have a column in my computer record with the id of the customer who owns the computer.  I am trying to show their name in a table next to the computers' and found a temporary solution.  I am using this in my view (which probably isn't proper MVC) and also makes the page take forever to load (I am showing 100 computers per page).

```
<td>
    <?php
        foreach ($customers as $customer):
            if ($computer->cust_id == $customer->id) {
                echo $this->Html->link(
                    $customer->first.' '.$customer->last,
                    ['controller'=>'Customers', 'action'=>'view', $customer->id]
                );
            }
        endforeach;
    ?>
</td>
```

I also tried to do `$this->Customers->get($computer->cust_id)` after loading the model in the Controller but it says I need a Customer Helper.  What is the CakePHP method of taking care of this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed a very basic question; have you read the manual and worked through the tutorial? In this case, it looks like you should be using containment to get the customer record when you first read the computer record, and then you'd just use `$computer->customer->first` etc. to reference it. Without seeing more of your code, though we can't say whether you even have your model associations set up correctly.

Comment: I tried using first but then when it comes to the next search, it can't find the entry because it narrows the query down to just that one item.  Is there a way around that?

Comment: `$computer->customer->first` would be the first name of the customer, nothing to do with the `->first()` call that you can do on queries.

Comment: Ah I see.  I'm just confused because I didn't know you can get from $computer->cust_id to $computer->customer.  So I somehow replace the cust_id with the customer object by searching by ID in controller?

Comment: You really need to read the manual, particularly the bits about [Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) and [Retrieving Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data). This is all very standard, simple stuff with tons of examples.

Comment: Okay I'll go read up on it.  I did the tutorial awhile ago but don't remember seeing anything about getting to the point.  I'll read those specifically.  Thanks for the direction!